# CTE keeps saying Type dont match between anchor and the recursive part

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Im having a CTE with defenition as follows

```
    ;With Paths as (
    select s.ID as RootID,t.subject_ID,t.Parent_ID ,t.text, CONVERT(nvarchar(max),t.text) as Path,convert(nvarchar(max),t.subject_ID) as P2
    from
        @search s
            inner join
        SubjectHierarchy t
            on
                s.ID = t.subject_ID 
    union all
    select p.RootID,t.subject_ID,t.Parent_ID,p.text, t.text + '$' + p.Path,convert(nvarchar(10),t.subject_ID) + '$' + convert(nvarchar(10),p.P2) 
    from Paths p
            inner join
        SubjectHierarchy t
            on
                p.Parent_ID = t.subject_ID 
)
```

But it keep saying the erorr

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Procedure f_fetchKeywordVocabullary, Line
>   30 Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in
>   column "P2" of recursive query "Paths".

Whats wrong with my conversion??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a recursive CTE the types in the `union all` have to match *exactly*. So, if you have an `nvarchar(max)` in the top part of the union, the corresponding attribute in the bottom part also has to be `nvarchar(max)`, not `nvarchar(10)`. Same goes for decimal datatypes; a `decimal(5, 3)` doesn't match a `decimal(15, 3)`.

This, of course, gets more complicated when types are not immediately identifiable, especially when doing concatenations and calculations. In those cases you want to wrap the concat/calculation in a convert: `CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 3), T1.DecimalAttribute/T2.DecimalAttribute)` or `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), T1.Text + T2.Text)`

Comment: Oh.. OK.. So every where it should match with the variable length.. isnt it? thanks a lot man.. Thats fixed...